# Convert Int Array into an Integer (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

Hi I'm a beginner in Swift and I'm wondering how I could turn an array of integers into just one integer.

```
var myArray: [Int] = [ 5, 3, 8]
// wanted output: 538
```

( I tried joined, but it turns it into a string )

Comment: let number = myArray.joinWithSeprator(""). try this. I think this will help you

Answer (score 7):

```
let myArray = [1,5,2]
var myString = ""
_ = myArray.map{ myString = myString + "\($0)" }
let myInt = Int(myString)
```

Works like a charm :)